# how to add background color for border of itextsharp pdf page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf-generation, itext

How can I add back ground color [not border line color] at out side of border[four sides] of itextsharp pdf page ..

I tride with this .. but Its not working for back ground color of out side of  border..

```
   content.EoFill();
   content.EoFillStroke();
   content.Fill();
   content.FillStroke();
```

but not working

```
public class pageborder : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
        var content = writer.DirectContent;
        content.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);
        content.RoundRectangle(35f,55f, 520f, 750f ,20f);
        content.Stroke();        
    }    
}
```

Comment: PDF does not contain operations to fill area *outside* a path. But it is flexible in its path creation methods. Thus, you have to create a path making the area you want to fill its *inside*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I add back ground color [not border line color] at out side of border[four sides] of itextsharp pdf page

I assume this to mean you want something like this:

[image: screenshot of page with colored frame]

You can create that by overriding `onEndPage` like this (this is Java code but the corresponding C# code should be easy to derive from it):

```
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    super.onEndPage(writer, document);
    PdfContentByte content = writer.getDirectContent();
    content.setColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
    content.rectangle(writer.getPageSize().getLeft(), writer.getPageSize().getBottom(),
                      writer.getPageSize().getWidth(), writer.getPageSize().getHeight());
    content.roundRectangle(35f,55f, 520f, 750f ,20f);
    content.eoFill();        
}
```

*(the complete sample: [CreateWithFrame.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/path/CreateWithFrame.java) method `testCreateFramedDocumentEoFill`)*

This works by adding another, page-sized rectangle to the path and using even-odd-fill. As the inner area is added to the path both as part of the original, rounded rectangle and the new rectangle, i.e. twice, it *is not* filled by `eoFill`. The area between the borders of the rectangles is only added once. Thus, it *is* filled by `eoFill`.

---

You can also use the normal `fill` method if you arrange subpath orientations accordingly, e.g.

```
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
{
    super.onEndPage(writer, document);
    PdfContentByte content = writer.getDirectContent();
    content.setColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
    content.rectangle(writer.getPageSize().getRight(), writer.getPageSize().getBottom(),
                     -writer.getPageSize().getWidth(), writer.getPageSize().getHeight());
    content.roundRectangle(35f,55f, 520f, 750f ,20f);
    content.fill();
}
```

*(the complete sample: [CreateWithFrame.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/path/CreateWithFrame.java) method `testCreateFramedDocumentFill`)*

Here the page-sized rectangle is added with negative orientation while the rounded rectangle is added with positive orientation. For the inner area of the rounded rectangle, therefore, the subpaths cancel out and the `fill` call does not fill.

Answer (score 0):

You have copy/pasted code to draw a page border:

```
public class pageborder : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        base.OnEndPage(writer, document);
        var content = writer.DirectContent;
        content.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);
        content.RoundRectangle(35f,55f, 520f, 750f ,20f);
        content.Stroke();        
    }    
}
```

Unfortunately, you don't understand what you've copied. You indeed need to replace `Stroke()` by `Fill()`, but that will fill the rectangle with the default fill color and you didn't define any fill color.

You also need to replace `SetColorStroke()` by `SetColorFill()`. For instance:

```
public class pageborder : PdfPageEventHelper
{
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        var content = writer.DirectContent;
        content.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
        content.RoundRectangle(35f,55f, 520f, 750f ,20f);
        content.Fill();        
    }    
}
```

Now you'll fill the rectangle with the rounded corners with red.